# Регулярное выражение для поиска блока текста между ограничителями

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Добрый вечер, мне необходимо разбить текст на состовляющие (есть листинги и абзацы, ну и предложения и тд).

Проблема в том как определить листинги
листинги выглядят приметрно так:

```
*Listing 1.
//:
some code
//~
*
```

вот я накидал пример регулярки которая ищет такое

```
String s = "((Listing )(\\d)+(\\.)\\n//:\n){1}((some code)*\n)+(//~){1}";
```

Может кто подскажет чего надо вместо "some code" писать чтобы искал листинг.
ибо я много чего пробовал , но не сильно работало.

И еще вопрос по поводу абзацев. У меня получилось что-то вроде:

```
String s ="(\n)(.)*";
```

Но опять же цепляет все где есть перевод на новую строку.

Может кто поможет раобраться с проблемой или посоветует чего)
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
/(?<=\/\/:)[\r\n]*(.*?)(?=[\r\n]*\/\/\~[\r\n]*\*)/sg
```

**[Посмотреть пример работы](http://regex101.com/r/rE7tA4)**

Comment: эмм.. спасибо ) 
но как-то не ищет ничего он

Comment: Добавил пример.

Comment: Извиняюсь, не понял немного)